# Could not save the csv file into folder using Django and Python

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to save some `.csv` files into folder using Python and Django but it's throwing the below error.

Error:

```
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

global name 'filename' is not defined
```

I am providing my code below.

```
report = Reactor.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
    for rec in report:
        if rec.status == 1:
            status = 'Start'
        if rec.status == 0:
            status = 'Stop'
        if rec.status == 2:
            status = 'Suspend'
        writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
    open(settings.FILE_PATH+filename,'w')
    return response
```

settings.py:

```
FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/upload/')
```

Here I wring the DB value into `.CSV` file and downloading it. In the same time I need to save that downloaded file into `upload` folder but getting those error.

Comment: `open(settings.FILE_PATH+filename,'w')` what is `filename` here ?

Comment: And why are you opening the file anyway just before you return?

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what the error is telling you. You haven't defined `filename` anywhere, but are calling it in `open(settings.FILE_PATH+filename,'w')`

Try:

```
filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.csv'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
```

Related, but not the problem that you're seeing, what's the point of opening the file for writing, but never writing anything to it?

Comment: ok, but my requirement is to save that downloaded file.you can check here `filename='+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.csv'`.

Comment: Hete I could able to download the file and I need to save that file before downloading.

Comment: But that's part of a string, that you're putting into `response`.

Comment: Its throwing error like `Exception Value:  

can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple` in this `open(settings.FILE_PATH+filename,'w')` line

Comment: No,Its storing the blank file.